# Difference between prvalue and lvalue when using casts

Tags: c++, casting

I understand the differences between lvalue and rvalue when casts are not involved. But it gets quite difficlt to understand the differences when casts are involved. Example:

```
static_cast<int&>(x) -- this is lvalue expression.
```

But why is the following a prvalue expression:

```
int i=9; 
int *k=&i;
int *m=&i;
int *const ptr=k;
const_cast<int*>(ptr)=m;
```

Even though it works but it is incorrect. It should have been :

```
const_cast<int*&>(ptr)=m; --note the & here
```

because

`const_cast<int*>(ptr)` is prvalue 
and
`const_cast<int*&>(ptr)=m;` is lvalue.

Can anybody explain why  `const_cast<int*>(ptr)=m;` a prvalue?
It in my opinion is a lvalue.

Comment: Do you even KNOW what it does?

Comment: Yes. Why you asking this but?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category

Comment: @soren : i read that. But specifically this example is not clear to me.

Comment: I don't think you know, maybe you should first explain what you expect `const_cast<int*&>(ptr)` to do, why you think it is a prvalue, and then clarify what exactly you are asking.

Comment: The assignment returns an lvalue.

Comment: @soren: I edited my question. The expression I used to ask my question was incorrect. I intend to assign m to ptr. But without constcast it wouldn't allow me because ptr is const pointer to int. Both the casts work well. But the first one is prvalue. My understanding says its lvalue. So could you please clarify where is my under standing going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cast to an lvalue reference type, you get an lvalue. If you cast to rvalue reference type, you get an xvalue. If you cast to a non-reference type, you get a prvalue and in the `const_cast` case, it's a *copy* of the original pointer, with different cv-qualification.

Simply put, if you want an lvalue, you need to cast to lvalue reference type.

Comment: Thanks brian. So in other words no matter what, I always have to use reference (or reference to ptr as in my case) to lvalue to get lvalue.    E.g. `const_cast <int*&>(lvalue)`      AND    Casting to an lvalue _pointer_ type wouldn't give me lvalue....instead it will give me prvalue    E.g. `const_cast <int*>(lvalue)` . Is it correct?

Comment: If const_cast <int*> is not called as lvalue pointer type then what is it called? Could you please clarify what is called what in case of `const_cast <int*> ` and  `const_cast <int*&>`

Comment: int* is pointer type. This expression could be lvalue or rvalue depending on the context. But iinmy example const_cast<int*>(ptr).  this expression should be lvalue right? Because ptr when cast to int* would have an identity and also it's address can be taken. So according to the rule it is lvalue. Right?

Comment: @anurag86 No you can't take the address of the return value of `const_cast<int*>(ptr)`. It's a temporary which is a copy of `ptr`.